# Como converter texto em entidades HTML de forma compatível com o CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, htmlentities

Preciso fazer uma busca textual em um conjunto de dados produzidos pelo CKEditor. Esse editor converte o texto em entidades HTML tal como:

```
Serviços oferecidos ---> Servi&ccedil;os oferecidos
```

O que eu preciso, curto prazo, é que quando o usuário entrar em um `input` com o valor "serviços", eu possa converter isso em `servi&ccedil;os` de modo a usar esse termo na busca. A princípio eu poderia fazer isso no lado cliente (JavaScript) ou servidor (Python), mas minha esperança é que o próprio CKEditor tivesse algum utilitário para me ajudar nisso...

Busquei no Google por algo nesse sentido - tanto específico do CKEditor quanto geral pro JavaScript, mas não encontrei nada (no máximo código que converte o básico - tipo `<` para `&lt;` - mas nada que fizesse uma conversão mais completa). Existe uma maneira simples e "limpa" de se fazer isso? (*Workaround:* criar um editor invisível, jogar o texto lá e pegar de volta usando o `getData`)

P.S. Estou usando o CKEditor 4.4.5, *Full package*. Suspeito que o responsável pela conversão de entidades seja o plugin ["Escape HTML Entities"](http://ckeditor.com/addon/entities) (*default* em qualquer instalação, desde o *Basic package*), mas não encontrei nenhuma documentação mais detalhada do mesmo exceto pelo mostrado na página de download (i.e. algumas configurações, e só).

Comment: Chegou a ver [`CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.tools.html#.htmlEncode)?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, mas esse método só faz as substituições básicas (pelo menos chamado como `htmlEncode(texto)`, sem nenhum parâmetro adicional).

Comment: Tem razão. Inclusive é esse plugin que você citou o responsável por settings como `entities_latin` e similares. O código-fonte dele está no github: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/entities/plugin.js

Comment: @bfavaretto Ótimo, eu queria mesmo ver os fontes desse plugin, mas não estava encontrando! Isso explica por que o `htmlEncode` não funcionava: o plugin atua no nível do editor, não a nível global (i.e. dois editores na mesma página podem um ter o plugin habilitado e outro desabilitado). Infelizmente ao ver os fontes não encontrei nenhuma função utilitária, mas acabei dando um jeito de chegar à função desejada depois de muita tentativa e erro... Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O CKEditor "cru" faz somente uma conversão básica, o responsável por converter a grande maioria das entidades é o plugin ["Escape HTML Entities"](http://ckeditor.com/addon/entities) - incluído por padrão em todas as distribuições. Infelizmente esse plugin não oferece uma função utilitária para se ter acesso às mesmas regras de conversão, mas após ler seu [código-fonte](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/entities/plugin.js) ([indicado por @bfavareto nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40960/como-converter-texto-em-entidades-html-de-forma-compat%C3%ADvel-com-o-ckeditor#comment80778_40960)) vi que ele adiciona uma regra ao `htmlFilter` de um editor específico.

A solução então é criar um editor escondido (argh!) e buscar essa regra, aplicando-a ao texto que se quer converter:

```
$('<textarea id="editor_escondido" style="display:none;"></textarea>').appendTo($("body"));
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("editor_escondido");
var converter = editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.textRules.rules[0].value;
converter("serviços"); // servi&ccedil;os
```

Nota: Para que o texto seja convertido exatamente como é feito pelo CKEditor, o ideal seria aplicar **todas** as regras de texto na ordem em que elas ocorrem na prática. Entretanto, como essa é a *única* regra no caso do editor padrão, somente ela é suficiente nesse caso

---

**Solução alternativa:** em vez de criar um editor escondido, criar somente um *mock object* e usá-lo na função `afterInit` do plugin:

```
var converter = (function() {
    var ret;
    var mock = {
        config: CKEDITOR.config,
        dataProcessor: {
            htmlFilter: {
                addRules:function(r) { ret = r.text; }
            }
        }
    };
    CKEDITOR.plugins.get("entities").afterInit(mock);
    return ret;
})();

converter("serviços"); // servi&ccedil;os
```